# How do I fix Illegal Start of Expressions with all of my methods?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have my code. I think it's all right, but it is not. It keeps telling me at the beginning of each method that there is a ';' expected and it's also an 'illegal start of expression' with the void. I do not know how to fix it. Can someone please help me fix these errors?

Here's an example of the Errors:

```
F:\COMP SCI\Topic 29  - Data Structures -- Robin Hood\Problem Set\RobinHoodApp.java:203: error: ';' expected
   void arrayList **()** throws FileNotFoundException();


F:\COMP SCI\Topic 29  - Data Structures -- Robin Hood\Problem Set\RobinHoodApp.java:212: error: illegal start of expression
     **void** output()


F:\COMP SCI\Topic 29  - Data Structures -- Robin Hood\Problem Set\RobinHoodApp.java:212: error: ';' expected
     void output **()**
```

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class RobinHoodApp{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException    {
        RobinHood app = new RobinHood();
        app.readFile();
        app.arrayList();
        app.wordCount();
        app.countMenAtArms();
        app.writeToFile();
    }
}

class RobinHood extends JFrame
{
    private static final ArrayList<String>words = new ArrayList<>();
    private static Scanner book;
    private static int count;
    private static int wordCount;
    public RobinHood()
    {


        try {
            //        scrubber();


            //Prints All Words 1 by 1: Works!


            book = new Scanner(new File("RobinHood.txt") );
            book.useDelimiter("\r\n");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
             out.println("Where's your text fam?");
        }
}

    void readFile()
    {

      while(book.hasNext())
        {
                    String text = book.next();
                    out.println(text);
        }

   void arrayList() throws FileNotFoundException();
    {
        Scanner add = new Scanner(new File("RobinHood.txt"));

        while(add.hasNext())
        {
            words.add(add.next());
        }
    }
     void output()
    {
        out.println(words);
    }

    void countMenAtArms()
    {
        //Shows 23 times
        String find = "men-at-arms";
        count = 0;
        int x;
        String text;

         for(x=0; x< wordCount; x++ )
        {
            text = words.get(x);
            text = text.replaceAll("\n", "");
            text = text.replaceAll("\n", "");
            if (text.equals(find))
            {
                count++;
            }

        }
        out.println("The amount of time 'men-at-arms' appears in the book is: " + count);
    }
//    void scrubber()
//    {
//
//    }
//
//

     void wordCount()
     {
        {
           wordCount=words.size();
           out.println("There are "+wordCount+" words in Robin Hood.");
        }
    }

    public void writeToFile()
    {
        File file;

            file = new File("Dominique.dat");
            try (FileOutputStream data = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
                if ( !file.exists() )
                    {
                        file.createNewFile();
                    }

                String wordCountSentence = "There are "+ wordCount +" words in Robin Hood. \n";
                String countTheMen = "The amount of time 'men-at-arms' appears in the book is: " + count;
                byte[] strToBytes = wordCountSentence.getBytes();
                byte[] menToBytes = countTheMen.getBytes();
                data.write(strToBytes);
                data.write(menToBytes);
                data.flush();
                data.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
               System.out.println("Error");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You missed a `}` after the while loop in `readFile`

Comment: Note that if you ask your IDE to format the code, you should be able to spot this easily. Also, when you get a slew of errors like this, if you look just before where the first one is, that's usually the real problem.

Comment: omg, thanks so much...I didn't see that. It's 2am where I am at the moment. I am currently going delirious.

Comment: *"I think it's all right, but it is not."* - Lesson #1.  The compiler is always correct.  *"It's 2am where I am at the moment"* - Lesson #2.  Don't try to program when you are too tired.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [a Java IDE like Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/ide/) when programming Java, it would point out to you the most obvious mistakes in your code.

- You missed a `}` after the `while` loop for your `readFile()` method (thanks to [Sweeper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5133585/sweeper) for this one).
- The syntax in your `arrayList()` method is wrong.

  ```
  void arrayList() throws FileNotFoundException();   {
  ```

No semicolon at the end of this defintion, no parenthesis at the end too, you are describing the class, not a method. Here is the correct way:

```
void arrayList() throws FileNotFoundException    {
```

- 1 useless `}` at the end of your class file.

Find below your code, with a proper layout and without syntax errors. Please use an IDE next time, that would avoid you an awful lot of trouble.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class RobinHoodApp   {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException    {
        RobinHood app = new RobinHood();
        app.readFile();
        app.arrayList();
        app.wordCount();
        app.countMenAtArms();
        app.writeToFile();
    }
}

class RobinHood extends JFrame
{
    private static final ArrayList<String>words = new ArrayList<>();
    private static Scanner book;
    private static int count;
    private static int wordCount;

    public RobinHood()
    {
        try {
            // Prints All Words 1 by 1: Works!

            book = new Scanner(new File("RobinHood.txt") );
            book.useDelimiter("\r\n");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            out.println("Where's your text fam ?");
        }
    }

    void readFile()
    {
        while(book.hasNext())
        {
            String text = book.next();
            out.println(text);
        }
    }

   void arrayList() throws FileNotFoundException
   {
        Scanner add = new Scanner(new File("RobinHood.txt"));

        while(add.hasNext())
        {
            words.add(add.next());
        }
   }

     void output()
     {
        out.println(words);
     }

     void countMenAtArms()
     {
        // Shows 23 times
        String find = "men-at-arms";
        count = 0;
        int x;
        String text;

         for(x=0; x< wordCount; x++ )
         {
            text = words.get(x);
            text = text.replaceAll("\n", "");
            text = text.replaceAll("\n", "");
            if (text.equals(find))
            {
                count++;
            }
         }

         out.println("The amount of time 'men-at-arms' appears in the book is: " + count);
    }

     void wordCount()
     {
        {
           wordCount=words.size();
           out.println("There are "+wordCount+" words in Robin Hood.");
        }
    }

    public void writeToFile()
    {
        File file;

        file = new File("Dominique.dat");
        try (FileOutputStream data = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            if ( !file.exists() )
            {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

                String wordCountSentence = "There are "+ wordCount +" words in Robin Hood. \n";
                String countTheMen = "The amount of time 'men-at-arms' appears in the book is: " + count;
                byte[] strToBytes = wordCountSentence.getBytes();
                byte[] menToBytes = countTheMen.getBytes();
                data.write(strToBytes);
                data.write(menToBytes);
                data.flush();
                data.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
               System.out.println("Error");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
throws FileNotFoundException();
```

This should be

```
throws FileNotFoundException
```

and similarly in all cases.

Rather trivial. Don't just make up the syntax. Look it up.